# Чтение из файла в массив в bash

Tags: файлы, массивы, bash

Есть файл, содержащий строки. Как прочитать из файла эти строки в массив в bash?

Comment: mapfile (или readarray, что одно и то же).

Answer (score 7):

Так гораздо проще:

```
readarray ARRAY < filename
```

Comment: почему минус? Ответ совершенно правильный (для bash 4). Я бы [опцию `-t`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-mapfile) ещё передал, чтобы перевод строки убрать.

Answer (score 3):

читаем:

```
index=0
while read line; do
    array[$index]="$line"
    index=$(($index+1))
done < filename
```

проверяем:

```
for ((a=0; a < ${#array[*]}; a++))
do
    echo "$a: ${array[$a]}"
done
```