# Элементы массива bash

Tags: bash

Есть такой .txt файл с такими вот значениями  "023 23ап" "1233 23"  "133 вр 3" мне нужно его считать в bash массив
Вот таком вот виде
Massiv = ("023 23ап" "1233 23"  "133 вр 3")

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Хм. Гугл вроде открывается. Google read file to array. 
А вообще дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/111951/190728

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Чтение из файла в массив в bash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/111951/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b2-bash)